# Yacc, structure pointers in union

Tags: c, pointers, structure, union, yacc

For some reason, the structure pointers in a union are seemingly not defined even though I include the `.h` beforehand.

```
%{
#include "agent.h"
.
.
.
%}
%union {int iValue; char sIndex; ASTnode *nPtr; litNode *litPtr; ruleNode *rulePtr; exprNode *expPtr; actNode *actPtr; conNode *conPtr};
.
.
.
%%
```

However, the function definitions that use such structure pointers under the `#include "agent.h"` work fine. Why do I get the error:

```
y.tab.h:58:15: error: unknown type name ‘ASTnode’
 typedef union {int iValue; char sIndex; ASTnode *nPtr; litNode *litPtr; ruleNode *rulePtr; exprNode *expPtr; actNode *actPtr; conNode *conPtr} YYSTYPE;
               ^
y.tab.h:58:15: error: unknown type name ‘litNode’
y.tab.h:58:15: error: unknown type name ‘ruleNode’
y.tab.h:58:15: error: unknown type name ‘exprNode’
y.tab.h:58:15: error: unknown type name ‘actNode’
y.tab.h:58:15: error: unknown type name ‘conNode’
```

even though I have included the `.h` file?

I have seen other questions regarding the issue but they have solved it by including the header file, but for my case, it still does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: See [`%code requires`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/_0025code-Summary.html) blocks, which are also copied into the generated header file.

Comment: Please, don't post a snippet of code showing _only_ the general structure of a `yacc(1)` source file.  It's assumed that the users listening in this forum know the structure of a `yacc(1)` file, and better format more visibly the structure of the `union` defined inside, as it is difficult to identify anything from the error messages, as everythin is on the same line.  BTW, show the definition of the type `ASTnode` as the error states that type is not defined anywhere, and you don't say anything about that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about an undefined type (`ASTnode`) which probably you have defined as a `struct`, but not with a `typedef` (in C++ a struct gets automatically a type defined with the same name, but that's not true in C) or that you have mispelled when using it in the `%union` sentence of yacc.

The problem has nothing to do with yacc.  You are using a type that is not declared anywhere.  Search for the definition of type `ASTnode` in your headers.  Probably you lack a `typedef` somewhere.

The same applies to the types

- `litNode`
- `ruleNode`
- `exprNode`
- `actNode`
- `conNode`

those types are application types, that you have to define before using them in the created `union` type.  They are most probably defined in a `.h` file that you have to include at the beginning of each file where you include the generated `y.tab.h` and in the C part (the one surrounded by `%{` and `%}`) to give the compiler access to those type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, I have to include the `.h` file before the declaration of including `y.tab.h`. So, I have to also include the `.h` inside the Lex file, before calling `include "y.tab.h"`

Comment: He doesn't seem to `#include` anything but the file `agent.h` which doesn't show anything.  The compiler message complaints about the undefined type `ASTnode` which probably has not been `typedef`ed anywhere, or is mispelled.  `y.tab.h` probably is not needed at all (it is never needed in the `y.tab.c` file generated)